# Can you trim rim tape once installed?

Tags: maintenance

I installed my rim tape then noticed was too wide so I trimmed it with a razor knife. Would this have caused any damage to the rim bead?

Comment: What kind of rim do you have? I seriously doubt anything bad can happen unless you run CF rims or tubeless.

Comment: I've done this once or twice, with stock AL rims.  I see no problem (though it does irritate one that it's so hard to find the right size rim tape).

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, depends how careful you are and if they are carbon rims.

I always do a 3cm test to get the best width, then take my time and gracefully cut the width of the entire roll with a cutter. 
Now you have a entire roll of the correct width and you just apply what you need.

Answer (score -1):

You can though I can say that in 40+ years or riding and many years of working in shops I've never once had to do this. Rim tapes come in various widths from various makers so you should be able to find one that will fit. Also a little too wide is far preferable to a tape that is a little too narrow.